# NSTextField bound to double in Swift, how to allow blank?

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift4, nstextfield, kvc

I'm using a NSTextField which I have bound to an integer via a binding in the storyboard. The Swift code looks like this:

```
@objc dynamic var quantity: Int = 0
```

This works great for validating numbers and I get a helpful message if there is an attempt to enter something invalid, for example alphabetic letters.

The problem I'm having is that the application is crashing when you tab out of the field without filling anything in. Following the error messages, the most relevant appears to be:

```
2019-03-09 16:29:46.813928+0000 ViewWebSocketLearning[34535:1969855] [General] [<ViewWebSocketLearning.OrderFormViewController 0x103131820> setNilValueForKey]: could not set nil as the value for the key show.
2019-03-09 16:29:46.825146+0000 ViewWebSocketLearning[34535:1969855] [General] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3d7b6ded __exceptionPreprocess + 256
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff69882720 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3d7b6c1f +[NSException raise:format:] + 201
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff3fbe8dbb -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setNilValueForKey:] + 81
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff3fac1450 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 331
    5   Foundation                          0x00007fff3faec38a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 271
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff3af0bf03 -[NSBinder _setValue:forKeyPath:ofObject:mode:validateImmediately:raisesForNotApplicableKeys:error:] + 473
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff3af0bccf -[NSBinder setValue:forBinding:error:] + 236
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff3b54c376 -[NSValueBinder _applyObjectValue:forBinding:canRecoverFromErrors:handleErrors:typeOfAlert:discardEditingCallback:otherCallback:callbackContextInfo:didRunAlert:] + 225
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff3b54c698 -[NSValueBinder applyDisplayedValueHandleErrors:typeOfAlert:canRecoverFromErrors:discardEditingCallback:otherCallback:callbackContextInfo:didRunAlert:error:] + 544
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff3b54c81a -[NSValueBinder _applyDisplayedValueIfHasUncommittedChangesWithHandleErrors:typeOfAlert:discardEditingCallback:otherCallback:callbackContextInfo:didRunAlert:error:] + 105
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff3b053e4e -[NSValueBinder validateAndCommitValueInEditor:editingIsEnding:errorUserInterfaceHandled:] + 460
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff3b053c5a -[_NSBindingAdaptor _validateAndCommitValueInEditor:editingIsEnding:errorUserInterfaceHandled:bindingAdaptor:] + 175
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff3b053b8d -[_NSBindingAdaptor validateAndCommitValueInEditor:editingIsEnding:errorUserInterfaceHandled:] + 240
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff3af83e2b -[NSTextField textShouldEndEditing:] + 368
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff3af44cc9 -[NSTextView(NSSharing) resignFirstResponder] + 499
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff3ada2522 -[NSWindow _realMakeFirstResponder:] + 258
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff3b058001 -[NSTextView(NSPrivate) _giveUpFirstResponder:] + 263
```

I am interpreting this as the NSTextField binding not accepting a nil entry, apparently caused by leaving the field blank.

How can I prevent this exception from occurring? For my application, it's perfectly fine to leave the field blank while working on something else.

Comment: Add a number formatter to the text field.

Comment: The error says the crash is related to the key `show` rather than `quantity`. `quantity` is non-optional and cannot be `nil`.

Comment: Show is defined pretty much the same way:
    @objc dynamic var show: Int = 0

Comment: When I look at the outlets, I see formatter is linked to a greyed-out "Number Formatter". Maybe I did something wrong previously here?

Comment: One minor thing to point out, I did previously select a number formatter of style "Decimal" and behavior OS X 10.4+ Default.

Comment: A non-optional integer bound (directly) to a text field cannot crash, `0` is displayed as `"0"`

Comment: Ideally I would like to not have the number 0 show in a field until a user has actually entered something because I would like to show the placeholder text to them.

Comment: very simple solution, in your model object override "setNilValueForKey:" check if key is show + call [self setValue:@(0) forKey:@"show"]; more https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Compliant.html

Comment: If the property is a scalar, override the setNilValueForKey: method to gracefully handle the case where a nil value is assigned to the scalar property. Your 0 is treated as nil

Comment: @MarekH The reason must be somewhere else. You cannot assign `nil` to a non-optional type and as I said a Swift `Int` value `0` is not treated as `nil`

Comment: -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setNilValueForKey:] + 81 -> this is a proof your swift MODEL object is in reality NSObject subclass (or behind the scenes due to bindings). No need to fight me, read the documentation i linked

Comment: and the proper way to handle this situation (allow blank/subset of values/string starting with letter k etc.) is validateValue: or validate<KEY>: read more about KVC and look for examples https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/ValidatingProperties.html PS: remember validateValue can overwrite entered value if you are not happy with what has user entered. Your crash is the show key.

Comment: PS: setValue:forKey: -> who will handle this method ? Int scalar type show/quantity? Nope it's your OrderFormViewController object. Put setNilValueForKey + breakpoint into this class and you will see a MIRACLE!

Comment: Thanks for the lively discussion! I have now tried subcalssing NSTextField and then overriding setNilValueForKey, validateValue and setValue to see if any of these get called in my situation but they don't appear to. As you say, I need to read this documentation about KVC more because I didn't anticipate needing a deep understanding of this in order to do what I thought was a simple validation. One question, how do I find out who the receiver is for setValue:forKey?

Comment: OrderFormViewController

Comment: OK checking... and looking for a MIRACLE!

Comment: The first commenter was right that most issues are solved by numberformatter. It is just not clear how you did your bindings

Comment: OK I overrode setNilValueForKey in OrderFormViewController and yes, the miracle occurred. This does get called so I'm now able to a little more gracefully handle the situation with: override func setNilValueForKey(_ key: String) {
        switch key {
        case "quantity":
            quantityTextField.stringValue = ""
        default:
            break
        }
    }

Comment: Final comment and then I'm going to mark this as solved: The placeholder disappears when you override setNilValueForKey so I put the placeholder text in IB under the "Null Placeholder" of the value binding.

Comment: @MarekH, if you want to answer this question I will mark your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using NSTextFields with bindings Cocoa uses the key-value coding methods (KVC) such as `setValue:forKey:` Bindings setup in Storyboard/XIB are always tied to NSObject subclass object (controller). Non-object values are handled specially:

> If your key-value coding compliant object receives a `setValue:forKey:`
>   message with nil passed as the value for a non-object property, the
>   default implementation has no appropriate, generalized course of
>   action. It therefore sends itself a setNilValueForKey: message, which
>   you can override. The default implementation of `setNilValueForKey:`
>   raises an `NSInvalidArgumentException` exception, but you can provide an
>   appropriate, implementation-specific behavior.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/HandlingNon-ObjectValues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107i-CH5-SW1

In your case `OrderFormViewController` didn't have overriden setNilValueForKey: method and it thrown exception.

Implementing `setNilValueForKey`: will solve all the issues.

PS: Using NSNumberFormatter or binding to a NSNumber object would solve the issue as well.